# What is status in chome

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I came across an oddity in chrome today.

```
var foo = ["70036", "70374"]
var status = ["70036", "70374"]

console.log(status[0]);
console.log(foo[0]);
```

Now you'd expect to get the following in the console:

```
70036
70036
```

However you get:

```
7
70036
```

So I opened a fresh chrome tab and type status into the console and I get "" back. I can see that status is a reserved word but I get no console error when trying to override it.

Comment: Made me wonder if this actually works in strict mode, but it does. I shouldn't have wondered though, as strict mode is about `this`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a property that is used for setting the Status bar message in browsers. As far as I am aware this doesn't do much in Chrome & FireFox, unless the user changes the settings.

ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/status